# intergation of flask for ML into a meteor.js app

Tags: reactjs, flask, meteor, computer-vision, pytorch

I have build a simple pure react and meteor web app. I am trying to connect a flask API to my meteor.js app for the machine learning component of my application. I have seen examples for pure react front end but cant get the same logic to work for meteor.

what I did is:

1. make a flask app and return the prediction results to localhost:5000 as a python dictionary e.g.

```py
{'class': 'bird', 'confidence':'0.8932'}
```

2. Set up a proxy in my meteor app in package.json, I have meteor app running at localhost:3000:

```
"proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
```

3. finally, this is where I am confused, I have a bunch of components in my home page, I am not sure if I have to render the flask results in a component or page, nor how to do that. What I tried Is to render the results in one of the components using the **useEffect, useState** functions.
4. I get an error that says something like I can't use this funtionality.

```js
function App() {
  const [predictedClass, setPredictedClass] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/prediction').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setPredictedClass(data.class);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying the full URL to the fetch? `fetch('http://localhost:5000/prediction')`

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 0):

I use the `useEffect` method to get the data from the requests of my api.

example:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    getData('GET', '/api/test')
      .then(response => {
        setData(response)
      })
      .catch(error =>
        console.log(error)
      );
}, []);
```

Where `getData` is a custom function that calls an axios request.